# lost of device from network using Bonjour api

Tags: c++, ios, macos, networking, mdns

I would like to find device lost of connection during communication. Bonjour keeps device entry in local cache with long TTL so if I find lost of communication with device than I want to call `DNSServiceReconfirmRecord` to verify device is till in network.

```
DNSSD_API DNSServiceReconfirmRecord(
DNSServiceFlags flags,
uint32_t        interfaceIndex,
const char      *fullname,
uint16_t        rrtype,
uint16_t        rrclass,
uint16_t        rdlen,
const void      *rdata
);
```

How can I get `rdata` values? can anyone guide me how to use `DNSServiceReconfirmRecord`? I have all required information except `rdata` on above function.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You should consider at the `rrtype` and then provide `rdata` appropriately. [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types) has list of DNS record types. The pointer `rdata` should point to the raw data of the resource record, i.e., either create it your self or find a library that can.

Example:

If `rrtype == kDNSServiceType_PTR` (`kDNSServiceType_PTR = 12`), then `rdata` must point to a "Pointer record" defined in [RFC 1035](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035).

Comment: Thanks. How can i create rdata my self on above example? I cant find anything in library. I am working on windows I can access to dnn-sd.h only.

Comment: You should follow the RFC linked to, or another definition if: `rrtype != kDNSServiceType_PTR`

Comment: I setup rdata as a NULL RDATA format. I can see function didn't succeeded and return error -65541. I check with wirehshark trace. there is no packet transmission during this function called.   DNSServiceReconfirmRecord(kDNSServiceFlagsForce, 0,"xyz._xxx._udp.local", kDNSServiceType_PTR, kDNSServiceClass_IN,27, bigNULL);

Comment: Why is rdlen = 27, when you provide zero bytes (by passing NULL pointer)?

Comment: What is your rrtype? And why?

Comment: rrtype: kDNSServiceType_PTR , I put 27 from wireshark packet trace during discovery process. For a setup I am just using one device so i can see all information from response packet received on query reply

Comment: Did you read the documentation? It says: rdlen The length, in bytes, of the resource record rdata.

Comment: I think i dont understood properly rdata format. I gone through RFC 1035 as per your link...is there any example ....

Comment: What is the argument for using kDNSServiceType_PTR?

Comment: ohh ya, that was my mistake, type: SRV.. I looked wrong trace with google cast....I am not so expert in network..

Comment: For rrtype = SRV = kDNSServiceType_SRV = 33, you should follow: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2782

Comment: As per the wiki link

Comment: @bbt Did you succeed?

Comment: I was on holidays last couple of days. I will check today and update you. meanwhile i have workaround this issues. main aim is behind this work is to remove lost device entries from local cache so what i did ,simple loop which keep polling after 1 s to identify lost of device and update GUI. bonjour provides details of device and second loop code identify lost of device instead of bonjour api.